# Nested If inside of if else javascript

Tags: reactjs, react-native, if-statement, logic

I'm creating a validation I have a text handler which is,

1. userName
2. password
3. passwordConfirm
4. EmailID
5. securityAnswer

```
state = {
    userDetails: {
        userName: '',
        password: '',
        passwordConfirm: '',
        EmailID: '',
        securityAnswer: ''

    }
}
```

on the submit I have a logic of **if else** that handles all my test scenarios

```
if (_.isEmpty(this.state.userDetails.userName) || _.isEmpty(this.state.userDetails.password) || _.isEmpty(this.state.userDetails.passwordConfirm) || _.isEmpty(this.state.userDetails.EmailID) || _.isEmpty(this.state.userDetails.securityAnswer)) {

    // first scenario
    if (this.state.userDetails.userName == '') {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            userNameResult: `Please choose your Username!`,
        })
    }

    // second scenario 
    if (this.state.userDetails.password == '') {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            userDetails: {
                ...this.state.userDetails,
                errorPassword: `Please enter your Password!`,
            }
        })
    }

    // third scenario 
    if (this.state.userDetails.password == '') {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            userDetails: {
                ...this.state.userDetails,
                errorPassword: `Please enter your Password!`,
            }
        })
    }

   .... // fourth scenario  and so on


} else {

    console.log(Proceed)

}
```

the problem is the nested if, inside the first if is not reading the whole scenario's

do you have any idea's? sorry for the noob question.

Comment: `_.isEmpty(this.state.userDetails.userName)` I am pretty sure you are using Lodash and if you do that, you don't need second if statements since isEmpty function from lodash will return true if it is an empty string. You can just get rid of all the ifs inside the first control statement

Comment: Hi @KyawSiesein How can I validate or how can i make sure if the first scenario is true or false to show the usernameResult validation message ?

Comment: `if(_.isEmpty(this.state.userDetails.userName)){}`

Comment: still now working :(

Comment: If it's because `_.isEmpty(this.state.userDetails.userName)` get into the validate, it should be true again in the first if nested? Only couldn't work if it's not because userName empty, is from another. try to `console.log` each one find which validate get int.

Comment: I try to console each one I think the setState is having a problem, It will not update the state string.

Comment: Maybe try to declare a empty `userNameResult` in state?